# Kotlin Multiplatform Error linkPodDebugFrameworkIos FAILED

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

The current error I`m having is:

- I build on android studio and no problem so far
- Run pod install and everything checks out
- I press build on XCode and this is the error I find.

```
Task :shared_core:linkPodDebugFrameworkIos FAILED
e: Could not find "/Users/xxxx/android/shared_core/build/classes/kotlin/ios/main/klib/shared_core.klib" in [/Users/xxxx/ios/Pods, /Users/mac/.konan/klib, /Users/mac/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.6.10/klib/common, /Users/mac/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.6.10/klib/platform/ios_x64]
```

It happens both with multiplatform 1.5.31 and 1.6.10.

Obs:

- The file is there.
- Both Xcode, Android Studio and Terminal and Cocoapods have Full Disk access.

Obs2: My Folder structure is

```
    - root folder
        - android folder
        - ios folder
```

Obs3: My podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name                     = 'shared_core'
    spec.version                  = '1.0'
    spec.homepage                 = 'Link to the Shared Module homepage'
    spec.source                   = { :git => "Not Published", :tag => "Cocoapods/#{spec.name}/#{spec.version}" }
    spec.authors                  = ''
    spec.license                  = ''
    spec.summary                  = 'Some description for the Shared Module'

    spec.vendored_frameworks      = "build/cocoapods/framework/shared_core.framework"
    spec.libraries                = "c++"
    spec.module_name              = "#{spec.name}_umbrella"

    spec.ios.deployment_target = '11'

                

    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH' => ':shared_core',
        'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME' => 'shared_core',
    }

    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build shared_core',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration=$CONFIGURATION \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.cflags="$OTHER_CFLAGS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.headers="$HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.frameworks="$FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS"
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
end
```

And here's my PodFile:

```
target 'MyTarget' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'shared_core', :path => '../android/shared_core'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

I really have no idea what's going one, this project built before, and nothing changed, and now it's not finishing the build.

Comment: Hi! I would like to add a guess, that maybe your ./gradlew or Gradle in general became unable to access this file?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I just gave full access to gradle, still nothing :(

Comment: The strangest thing here is that in the list of search locations, there is no mention of your `android/shared_core`. Maybe you could try fetching this module out of the Android part and place it in the middle? The result should look like three folders - android, ios and shared.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev putting the ios folder inside the android folder with the kmm module seems to have done the trick!

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev it seems that the error wasn't solved, it comes and goes seemingly randomly.

Comment: I decided to create an issue on Kotlin https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51677